# Could not find .Main, error with Ant when I try to Run it

Tags: java

This is my first time using ant and one of my first times I program in java so I'm a little lost, I'm trying to compile and run a program with ant, it seems that it compiles right, but I have problems make it run, it says that it Couldn't find Tarea2.Main.

So this is the structure of my project file:

Tarea 2/

- src/tarea/pkg2
- build.xml
- 3rd party .jar

Inside src/tarea/pkg2 I have all my .java, and the .java that has the main method is called Tarea2.java.

And this is my build.xml:

```
<project name="Tarea2" default="run" basedir=".">
 <property name="src" location="src"/>
 <property name="build" location="build"/>
 <target name="init">
  <tstamp/>
  <mkdir dir="${build}"/>
 </target>
 <path id="classpath">
  <fileset dir=".">
   <include name="**/*.jar"/>
  </fileset>
 </path>
 <target name="compile" depends="init">
  <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${build}" includeantruntime="false">
   <classpath refid="classpath"/>
  </javac>
 </target>
 <target name="run" depends="compile">
  <java classname="Tarea2.Main" classpath="${build}">
   <classpath refid="classpath"/>
  </java>
 </target>
</project>
```

So I write "ant" in cmd from windows and everything is ok, except in the "run" target, in which I got stuff like:

[java] Could not find Tarea2.Main. Make sure you have it in your classpath

[java] at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecuteJava.execute

...

Somebody can help me pls?.

Comment: Are you sure you didn't mean `<java classname="Tarea2" ...>`?  With static method "main()" implicit?

Comment: I found it weir, but I saw this from other ppl too, and just now I tried with <java classname="Tarea2" ...> and didn't work too...